# Mongo Write in spark taking long time

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I have around 7 million records in a dataset and I am writing in mongo
using this

```py
mongo_db_conn_options = {
    "uri": self.MONGO_CONNECTION_URI.format(collection_name=collection_name),
    "database": self.MONGO_DB_CONFIG[MongoDBConstants.DB_NAME],
    "collection": collection_name,
}

dataframe.write.format("mongo").mode("append").options(**mongo_db_conn_options).save()
```

and it is taking around 50 mins. I checked in spark UI - this step is taking all the time **foreachPartition at MongoSpark.scala:130**

Can you please suggest some ways to optimize this?

I did one thing to optimize that I wrote all the data to s3 and read it again to write to mongo. I also tried persisting data but that did not seem to help much.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know exactly where the issue is coming from based on your message but few leads:

- Spark side

You need to make sure your spark code is optimized and there is no bottleneck here. Use the UI, explain command, ... to see that.
In order to optimize, you need to play with partitioning, caching, serialization, shuffles, ...

- Mongo side

Don't hesitate to use mongo tools to check your ongoing queries when you launch your job, this will help optimize, tools like opsmanager, mongostat, ... can help a lot

If you have indexes on the collections, you can have a huge overhead when trying to mass write in the collection, so one strategy is to drop the indexes, write, and re-create them. You can try that.

The writing to mongo depends on the partitions, the more partitions you have, the more you can parallelize the writing, you can try to tweak that too.

Hope this can help.